# Geting lat and lon from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to get the latitude and longitude of a facebook location given its id?
when i fetch the user object for my fb account it is clear in the JSON

```js
["location":{"id":"106423786059675","name":"Buenos Aires, Argentina"}].
```

Well, if I could query the lat and lon for the location id 106423786059675 would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try checking the API for that page's details?

http://graph.facebook.com/106423786059675

returns lots of information, even without needing an access token, including:

> "location": {
>         "latitude": -34.6033,
>         "longitude": -58.3817    },

Comment: No i didn't chek it before you tell me. It is great and you can bet that i am gona use it. You don't have the idea of how much i appretiate your tip. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you can do this:

```
$fb_location_id = 'LOCATION_ID';
$jsonurl        = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_location_id;
$json           = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output    = json_decode($json);
// the latitude
$fb_latitude    = $json_output->location->latitude;
// the longitude
$fb_longitude   = $json_output->location->longitude;
```